# How do I give my code permission to delete files

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I got my code which delete some files, Its kinda weird because its not throwing me any errors.

Essentially whats happening is that, its not deleting any files in the folder(not sure why) I've tried giving it permission to delete Only-Read files but that didnt work.

I've tried debugging but its not showing me anything.

And I understand that it cannot delete files that are being used somewhere else, I've tried deleting a few files manually and that worked, not sure why my code is not doing it automatically though, because if it hits an error it should move on the the next file right?

(This mainly applies to .rar files but also with some folders)

```
private void Clear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{



    string tempPath = Path.GetTempPath();
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(tempPath);

    foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in di.GetDirectories())
    {
        try
        {
            dir.Delete(true);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // Log error.
            continue;
        }
    }

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    //foreach (FileInfo file in di.GetFiles())
    foreach (FileInfo file in di.GetFiles())
    {
        try
        {
            file.Delete();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // Log error.
            continue;
        }
    }

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // string[] extentionList = new[] { "*.jpg", "*.rar", "*.bmp", "*.gif" };

    //Delete RAR Files
    foreach (FileInfo file in di.GetFiles("*.rar"))
    {
        try
        {
            file.Delete();
        }
        catch
        { 
            //log error I tried running it without the "Continue;" but it still wouldnt log me an error.
            continue;
        }

        }
```

Comment: None of those `file.Delete()`s and `dir.Delete()` work?

Comment: Does it enter the foreach loop?

Comment: I think if any files are already using by any other programs, then it will not allow to delete

Comment: It is working but only for some items, I cant see why its not working for other items because its not throwing me a error log or message

Comment: @Alexander.Matt Since you are **ignoring** exceptions by using `continue` you will not get an exception. In the `catch` block, catch exception by adding a variable name after `Exception` clause, something like: `Exception ex`, then replace `continue` with `Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());`. Start your application in Debug mode and monitor exceptions in Output window. Also, files and folders in user and system related locations (Usually `C:`) require appropriate authentication. You might need to grant admin rights to your app.

Comment: Thank you! Will look into this! Very helpful!